# Saving form data into dynamic form when hitting back or refreshing page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Right now I have code to dynamically add input fields to my form. I want to be able to submit the data and go to the next page but if someone decides to go back, the newly made input fields would still be there with the data. The way I have it set up now is to echo onto the input fields which works with the first two but not the third.

When I hit back, I get this:

[image: when I hit back]

Here is my code:

```
<h2>Enter Beneficiaries for Tangible Personal Property:</h2>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <div class="input_fields_container">
            <tr>
                <td>Name:<input type="text" name="ben[]" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['ben']['0'];?>" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                <td>Percentage of tangible personal property:<input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['percent']['0'];?>" style="width: 40px" name="percent[]" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="add" id="add" class="add_more_button" value= "Add Another" ></input></td>
            </tr> 
        </table>
    </div>
    <p style="color:red;"></p>
    <h3>Enter Contingent Beneficiary: </h3>
    Name:<input type="text" name="conben" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['conben'];?>" >
    <br><br>
    <button type="button" name="back" value="back" onclick="location.href='county.php'">Back</button>
    <input type="submit" name="submitform" value="Next"></input>
    <button type="button" name="download" onclick="location.href='downloadAdd.php'">Download will</button>
</form>

<script>
//script to add/remove fields
$(document).ready(function () {
    var getControl=getCookie("countControls1");
    var max_fields_limit = 2; // Set limit for maximum input fields
    var x = 0; // Initialize counter for text box

    for(var i=1; i<=getControl; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        addControls();
    }

    $('.add_more_button').click(function (e) { // Click event to add more fields
        addControls();
    });

    function addControls()
    {
        console.log(x);
        if (x < max_fields_limit ) { 
            x++; // Increment counter
            setCookie("countControls1",x,100);
            $('.input_fields_container').append('<div><tr id="row'+x+'"><td> Name:<input type="text" name="ben[]" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['ben']['1'];?>" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td>&nbspPercentage of tangible personal property:<input type="number" min="0" max="100" style="width: 40px" name="percent[]" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['percent']['1'];?>" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><a href="#" class="remove_field" style="margin-left:10px;">Remove</a></td></tr>');; // Add input field
         }
        else if (x==2){
            $("p").text("*Only 3 tangible beneficiaries are allowed.");
        }
    }

    $('.input_fields_container').on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { // User click on remove text links
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
        $("p").text("");
        setCookie("countControls1",x,100);
     });

    function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays)
    {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
        $("#div1").html("Add cookie = ",getCookie(cname));
    }

    function getCookie(cname) 
    {
        console.clear();
        var name = cname + "=";
        var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
        //console.log(cname);
        //console.log(decodedCookie);
        console.log(ca);
        for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                console.log(c.substring(name.length, c.length));
                return (c.substring(name.length, c.length));
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
});

</script>
```

Is there anyway to achieve this in this way or do I need to implement something else?

Comment: Could you recheck and reformat the HTML in first 10 lines. For example the opening <table> tag is missing.

Comment: Also the correct way for an input tag is <input ..... > and not close with </input> as you have done.

Comment: In general though, its much better not to embed PHP in your HTML code. Instead make a separate PHP file and submit the HTML from to it. Its easier then to let the PHP code control the creation of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write the fields back using a loop because presumably you have the two arrays in your session. You should also use `empty()` or `isset()` to check if the session arrays exist first otherwise you will end up with warnings about undefined keys and such:

```
<tr>
    <td>Name:<input type="text" name="ben[]" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['ben']['0'];?>" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
    <td>Percentage of tangible personal property:<input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['percent']['0'];?>" style="width: 40px" name="percent[]" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
    <td><input type="button" name="add" id="add" class="add_more_button" value= "Add Another" /></td>
</tr>
<?php
# Remove the first keys since you already used them above
unset($_SESSION['percent'][0],$_SESSION['ben'][0]);
# Just do a normal loop to create any remaining values
foreach($_SESSION['percent'] as $key => $value): ?>
<tr>
    <td>Name:<input type="text" name="ben[]" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['ben'][$key];?>" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
    <td>Percentage of tangible personal property:<input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" style="width: 40px" name="percent[]" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```